# I want to create two visualforce components so that the second can only be included if it is included inside the first

Tags: visualforce

I want to create visualforce component similar to say pageblocktable. If you see the behaviour of pageblocktable it can only be included inside a pageblock. similarly columns can be included inside pageblocktable/datatable.

I want to replicate the same in my custom visualforce component such that component B can only be included inside component A.(both A and be are custom visualforce component)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `<apex:attribute name="myValue">` and assign it to a boolean variable inside of `component a` and than use that to determine if it's coming from `component b` to determine if the parent is correct.

Comment: well this do the work but while developing(using the component in the page) I have to manually set the value for this attribute. Any other work around?

Answer (score 0):

If component B is always required within component A... why not build your B component within A component. Pass in "null" for attributes if you want component A without a component B.